# Facebook blocks my IP when sharing using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have a site which keeps sharing to Facebook using Graph API. All of a sudden, it was blocked by Facebook (the domain name I think). How can I avoid being blocked or is there some sort of permission I need to do so Facebook would allow me.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151